# set readonly attribute to keep the input editable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Is it possible to set "readonly" attribute of an input to keep it editable?

I'm doing a crossword and I can change my function to search for/select a tag using different attribute but I'm still wondering if it is possible.

Thanks for help in advance!

Comment: Huh? You want to make something readonly to make it editable? This doesn't make sense.

Comment: if i get you right you could use some additional class to mark fields which are not empty. or take a look at http://html5demos.com/contenteditable property

Answer (score 6):

If the JavaScript `readOnly` property is set to `true` (a boolean, not a string), then the control will not be editable.

If the JavaScript `readOnly` property is set to `false` (a boolean, not a string), then the control will be editable.

If the HTML `readonly` attribute is present, then the `readOnly` property will default to `true`.

If the HTML `readonly` attribute is not present, then the `readOnly` property will default to `false`.

JavaScript can modify the `value` property of a control no matter what state the `readOnly` property has.

There is no way for a control to be edited through the normal browser UI if it is set to `readOnly` (JavaScript consoles and DOM inspectors are not the normal UI).

Comment: **If the JavaScript readonly property is set to false (a boolean, not a string), then the control will be editable.** No, that's not true, at least not in my browser (Chrome). See the jsfiddle from my answer.

Comment: My idea was to keep the input editable and maintain the "readonly" attribute as a selector.

Thanks a lot for your help, very useful. I will change the selector in most functions.
I have to chenge the selectors

Comment: @KooiInc — You are using `setAttribute`, that sets the attribute, not the property. To set the property you would do: `HTMLInputNode.readonly = false;`.

Comment: @Quentin: see the updated jsfiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/KooiInc/ECw6A/). `HTMLInputNode.readonly = false` doesn't work (but `HTMLInputNode.disabled = false` does)

Comment: @KooiInc — Spotted [and fixed](http://jsfiddle.net/uneKD/) the problem, it is [`readOnly`](http://www.w3.org/TR/2003/REC-DOM-Level-2-HTML-20030109/html.html#ID-88461592) not `readonly`.

Answer (score 0):

The attribute `readonly` renders the input control noneditable for a user. Using javascript you can still change its value. Setting the `readonly` attribute in javascript to `false` has no effect for the user, the input still will be `readonly`. Removing the attribute will render the input editable for the user again.

You could also use the `disabled` attribute, with two differences: the field is displayed grayed out, and you *can* set the `disabled` attribute directly.

It's all tested/demonstrated in [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KooiInc/ECw6A/) [**note**: updated]

Comment: If you are using `setAttribute` (which I wouldn't for this) then you should be using `setAttribute('readonly', 'readonly')` and `removeAttribute('readonly')`.

Answer (score -1):

I suggest using the html5 supported data- prefix
data-readonly="true"
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_data_attributes